# TYPO3 9 CKEditor adds additional paragraths

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm using Typo3 9.5.10 with the CKEditor.

For a extension we reused the tt_content **subheader** and changed the type from **input** to **text**.

Since we are on CKEditor, the CMS or the editor adds new line breaks between tags on save. When open the element, the editor converts them to new paragraphs.

We don't use flux, I tryed these configurations:

```
editor:
  config:
    ignoreEmptyParagraph: true
    autoParagraph: false
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
```

Does anyone know that and found a solution?